# IPv6 address entropy and hashing

Tags: hash, hashmap, ip-address, ipv6, entropy

I have one thread that delegates incoming IPv6 connections to X worker threads, where connections with the same IPv6 source address should always be sent to the same worker thread. However, given a large amount of connections from all over the Internet, I also want to minimize the differences in load all X worker threads have to take on (i.e. in any given large time interval all worker threads should be entrusted with connections with approximately the same number of unique IPv6 addresses).

The most naive way to do so would be to interpret all or a section of the IPv6 address as a number N, and send it to the worker thread with index [N mod X]. However, IP addresses have low entropy (i.e. some bits are (un)set more often than others and thus are quite unrandom), so that would result in poor load balancing among the worker threads.

Clearly some kind of low-cost hashing needs to performed on the addresses to get keys with higher entropy. So are there documented solutions for this problem? Doesn't need to result in fantastic randomness, just something known to work reasonably well with IPv6 addresses.

*Edited to remove the sentence about avoiding collisions (because in this scenario, collisions are actually totally fine).*

Comment: Is round-robin scheduling out of the question?

Comment: @thuovila That's of course possible, but the reason I want to delegate based on IP address, is to minimize memory sharing. To prevent DOS attacks I have to match IP addresses against a cache of recent abusers, and by associating any given IP address with a fixed worker thread, I would be able to store the caches in exclusive thread local memory, thus boosting performance.

Comment: Crypto and hashing is definitely not my area of expertise and I know it, but a quick google turns up US patent 7,821,925 which in turn refers to this [hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_hashing)

Comment: The FreeBSD people seem to have written a solution for this: http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-hackers/2006-November/018661.html. Keep in mind that every hash where the number of possible outputs is smaller than the possible number of inputs will always have collisions.

Comment: @Sander Thanks for the relevant link. Looking back, I realize I worded the bit about collisions incorrectly. Since I only have a limited amount of threads (less than the amount of CPU cores), all of which are intended to handle many concurrent connections, collisions are totally irrelevant (as far as I can see in my current foggy and tired state). I just need a small number of hashes with reasonably even probabilities. So yeah, I should be able to adapt/simplify the algorithm mentioned in that link to suit my needs.

Comment: I think you meant [uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28discrete%29) instead of collisions

Comment: Well, I avoided that term because it doesn't need to be a perfectly uniform distribution, just "more uniform" than any sequence in an IPv6 address as-is, but yeah.